# Spring-boot repository not being registered as a valid bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Spring-boot does not seem to want to register my repository as a valid bean :( Here is the error I am seeing:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.frustrated.stats.MyRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

The underlying cause seems to be:

```
o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Ignored because not a concrete top-level class: file [/Users/me/Code/my_app/my_service/build/classes/java/main/com/frustrated/stats/MyRepository.class]
```

Have I configured my application improperly somewhere?

Here are my files:

**MyRepository.java**:

```
package com.frustrated.stats;

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<StatsEvent, Long> {}
```

**StatsEvent.java**:

```
package com.frustrated.stats;

@Entity
public class StatsEvent { ... }
```

**Application.java**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.frustrated" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

Here is my package structure:

```
com:
  frustrated:
    - Application.java
    stats:
      - MyRepository.java
      - StatsEvent.java
```

**Attempts to Debug**

After trying a lot of different annotations, I thought it may be more productive to simply step through the registration process. I have traced the code, and it seems to be failing [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/1c40e36839b45c5a1dfb06ad85c65a21dd3be235/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java#L526):

```
    protected boolean isCandidateComponent(AnnotatedBeanDefinition beanDefinition) {
        AnnotationMetadata metadata = beanDefinition.getMetadata();
        return (metadata.isIndependent() && (metadata.isConcrete() ||
            (metadata.isAbstract() && metadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(Lookup.class.getName()))));
}
```

It is the `metadata.hasAnnotatedMethods(Lookup.class.getName())` that is false and causing my repository to not be instantiated as such.

It may also be of note that my `StatsEvent` is also ignored because:

```
o.s.c.a.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner   : Ignored because not matching any filter: file [/Users/me/Code/my_app/my_service/build/classes/java/main/com/frustrated/stats/StatsEvent.class]
```

*Any help would be greatly appreciated!*

Comment: @EnableJpaRepositories.

Comment: Judging by `MyRepository` extending `JpaRepository`, you are trying to use Spring Data JPA but your have excluded the auto-configuration of Hibernate. Do you have some manual configuration for Hibernate or another JPA provider that you haven't shown?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson you are embarrassingly (for me) correct. Want to make your comment an answer so I can accept it? Removing the excludes for DataSource and JPA did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by MyRepository extending JpaRepository, you are trying to use Spring Data JPA but your have excluded the auto-configuration for Hibernate and a DataSource. Unless you have some manual configuration for Hibernate or another JPA provider that you haven't shown, the support for `JpaRepository` will be disabled as it requires a JPA provider and a data source.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this on top of your Application.class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.frustrated.stats.MyRepository")
@ComponentScan("com.frustrated.stats.service") // if you have it
@EntityScan("com.frustrated.stats.entity") // of your entities
```

Comment: I think `@EntityScan` and `@ComponentScan` should be uneccessary with current annotations and structure, `@EnableJpaRepositories` also did not seem to help. But these were also all things I thought may have been the cause! I think @AndyWilkinson got it in his comment though